# Замена sed с использованием цикла

Tags: linux, bash, while, sed

У меня есть `file1`:

```
70 0\n
71 0\n
72 0\n
73 0\n
```

И `file2`:

```
70 6\n
72 14\n
73 19\n
```

Вопрос: как командой `sed`, используя цикл, получился вывод???:

```
70 6\n
71 0\n
72 14\n
73 19\n
```

Должно быть примерно так, но не работает:

```bash
while read i; do sed -i "s/'сat i | awk '{ print $1 }''/$i/g' file1; done < file2
```

Это у меня не работает, и я не знаю правильный синтаксис.
Помогите, пожалуйста, это мой первый вопрос на ресурсе, спасибо.

`\n` - знак переноса строки

Comment: Можно ли считать, что задача сводится к следующей --  есть 2 файла, отсортированных по значению первого поля и требуется получить файл, состоящий из всех строк второго файла, плюс все строки из первого файла, которых (по значению первого поля) нет во втором файле?

Answer (score 2):

`Awk` для этого подойдет лучше:

```
$ cat f1
70 0
71 0
72 0
73 0

$ cat f2
70 6
72 14
73 19

$ awk '{arr[$1]=$2}END{for(i in arr)print i,arr[i]}' f1 f2
70 6
71 0
72 14
73 19
```